# How to automatically include NPM "dependencies" into index.html through <script> tags in VUE JS WEBPACK project?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, vuejs2, vue-cli

I know there is a GRUNT-BOWER plugin which automatically includes the BOWER dependencies into index.html file through  tags every time you install any new bower package.

Is there any similar tool which automatically Injects / includes the NPM dependencies into index.html ?

FYI the project is a VUE-CLI WEBPACK project. Can this be achieved through WEBPACK or do i need a dedicated build tool for doing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using already using webpack you can have a look at [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#basic-usage). It will create a `.html` file with your bundles added as script tags.

html-webpack-plugin in conjunction with creating a [vendor bundle](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/#passing-the-minchunks-property-a-function) should help with this problem.